# сравнение вводных в классах

Tags: java, массивы

Если не обращать внимания на то, что этот код криво-косо написан...
По идее, теперь я должен сравнить значения `sX` и `sY` c `x2`,`y2` и если `true` - новый символ и "попадание", если `false` - другой символ и "промах"?
И если логика верна, как это лучше реализовать?

```
import com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.SourceTree;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SeaBattle3 {

    private static final char[][] field = new char[10][10];

    public static void battleField() {
        for ( int k = 1; k < 11; k++ ) {
            System.out.print( k + "\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {

                field[j][i] = '.';
                System.out.print( field[j][i] + "\t" );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void logicOfPlaceOfShip() throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Введите координату Х: " );
        //BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        //String x = reader.readLine();
        //char x2 = x.charAt(0);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
        int x = scanner.nextInt();
        int x2 = x - 1;
        System.out.println( "Вы ввели " + x );
        System.out.println( "Введите координату Y: " );
        //String y = reader.readLine();
        //char y2 = y.charAt(0);
        int y = scanner.nextInt();
        int y2 = y - 1;
        System.out.println( "Вы ввели " + y );

        System.out.println( "Корабль поставлен в месте с координатами " + x + " , " + y );
        for ( int k = 1; k < 11; k++ ) {
            System.out.print( k + "\t" );
        }
        System.out.println();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
            for ( int j = 0; j < 10; j++ ) {
                field[j][i] = '.';
                field[x2][y2] = 'O';
                System.out.print( field[j][i] + "\t" );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public static void shoot() throws Exception {
        System.out.println( "Введите координаты выстрела: " );
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner( System.in );
        int sX = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Координата по Х = " + sX );
        int sY = sc1.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "Координата по Y =" + sY );
        sc1.close();
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        battleField();
        logicOfPlaceOfShip();
        shoot();
    }
}
```

Comment: `при копировании все поехало, извиняйте` - ну так отформатируй. это вроде не сложно

Comment: С этим кодом что-то не так? Или это запрос на инспекцию кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что мешает присохранить значения в полях класса и позже сравнить непонятно, но вот пример( не люблю статику - мешает жить ):

```
private /*static*/ final char[][] field = new char[10][10];

private Point ship, shot;

public /*static*/ void battleField() {
    ...
}

public /*static*/ void logicOfPlaceOfShip() throws Exception {
    ...
    ship = new Point( x, y );
}

public /*static*/ void shoot() throws Exception {
    ...
    shot = new Point( sX, sY );
}

public void check() {
    System.out.println( "Ship " + ship );
    System.out.println( "Shot " + shot );
    System.out.println( ship.equals( shot ) ? "Попадание" : "Промах" );
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    SeaBattle3 zz = new SeaBattle3();
    zz.battleField();
    zz.logicOfPlaceOfShip();
    zz.shoot();
    zz.check();
}

private class Point {
    public final int x, y;
    public Point( int x, int y ) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object object ) {
//      if ( object == null )
//          return false;
        if ( ! (object instanceof Point) )
            return false;
        if ( ((Point)object).x != this.x )
            return false;
        if ( ((Point)object).y != this.y )
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Point: x=" + x + ", y=" + y;
    }
}
```

Comment: небольшой оффтоп: `не люблю статику - мешает жить` - а сеттеры и геттеры тоже?

Comment: а почему вы статику не любите?) Имхо всё что может быть статикой, должно быть ею...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Если вопрос про вспомогательный класс - кортеж `Point` - то да. P.S. Ну блин докопались до фразы)

Comment: @AndreyM нет, я про геттеры и сеттеры) Просто интересно вы последователь Егора Бугаенко или нет))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Не, не последователь, но всего должно быть в меру, золотая середина так сказать-с.